# materializcess carousel does not init (

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, materialize

I have a strange problem with carousel (https://materializecss.com/). Somtimes it works, but somtimes i receive the following error:

jQuery.Deferred exception: c is undefined s@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js:6:158232
TypeError: c is undefined[Weitere Informationen]

I am using jquery 3.2.1 and materialize 0.100.2 on firefox. This issue also appears on edge. It works mostly with Chrome.

Here is my HTML code:

```html
  <div class="hide-on-small-only blue-grey lighten-5">
    <div id="section-industry" class="container section-padding">
      <div id="crsl-industry" class="carousel">
        <a class="carousel-item" href="#cimg1" data-industry="Pulp & Paper"><img src="img/industry/pulp_and_paper.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="#cimg2" data-industry="Corrugated Packaging"><img src="img/industry/corrugated_packageing.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="#cimg3" data-industry="Paper Converting"><img src="img/industry/paper_converting.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="#cimg4" data-industry="Starch & Flour"><img src="img/industry/starch_and_flour.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="#cimg5" data-industry="Food & Beverage"><img src="img/industry/food_and_beverage.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="#cimg6" data-industry="Adhesives"><img src="img/industry/adhesives.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="#cimg7" data-industry="Environmental Engineering"><img src="img/industry/environmental_engineering.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="carousel-item" href="#cimg8" data-industry="Engineering Construction"><img src="img/industry/engineering_construction.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
      <h4 id="label-industry" class="center-align bvg-blue-text" style="padding-top: 40px"></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my js code:

```js
  $('#crsl-industry').carousel({indicators: true, onCycleTo: function(element) {
    $('#label-industry').text($(element).data('industry'));
  }});

  $('.carousel-item').click(function() {
    $('#crsl-industry').carousel('next');
  });
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#crsl-industry').carousel('next');
  }, 2000);
```

I'am not sure whats wrong? Is that an browser issue?
Please advice.

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it fixed. webcompat.com suggested it might be a race condition. It turned out to be true.
You can not use the code in `$(document).ready()`. Instead put the code `$(window).on('load', function() {/*code*/});`

The code working for me looks like this:

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {

  $('#crsl-industry').carousel({indicators: true, onCycleTo: function(element) {
    $('#label-industry').text($(element).data('industry'));
  }});
  
  $('.carousel-item').click(function() {
    $('#crsl-industry').carousel('next');
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    $('#crsl-industry').carousel('next');
  }, 2000);
});
```